# Overly verbose logging in jest tests

Tags: node.js, jestjs, yarnpkg, winston, yarnpkg-v2

```
➤ YN0000: [@bb/graph]:     console.log
➤ YN0000: [@bb/graph]:       info:     after all completed
➤ YN0000: [@bb/graph]: 
➤ YN0000: [@bb/graph]:       at Console.log (../.yarn/cache/winston-npm-3.3.3-3fa4527b42-8a9d69c642.zip/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports/console.js:79:23)
```

I'm getting this overly verbose output (mostly I don't want to see the `console.log` stuff, just `info:     after all completed` in my test output.

I'm using yarn2, jest, and winston, I don't think it's winston because it doesn't support logging line numbers, and this isn't happening when I start my server outside of a test. I don't think it's yarn2 either because it happens when I run `yarn workspace @bb/graph test`, which doesn't include the prefix. This makes me guess that it's jest. Here's my config.

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
  coverageReporters: [
    'text-summary',
  ],
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      branches: 50,
      functions: 65,
      lines: 80,
      statements: 80,
    },
  },
  setupFiles: ['./jest.setup.js'],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testMatch: ['**/__tests__/**/*.ts', '**/*.test.ts'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/build/'],
};
```

everything else is defaults.

Comment: For anyone who ends up here, this has been open as an issue without movement for almost a year now. Feel free to contribute to the discussion to drive attention to the issue. https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10322